# Anyway to Limit MySQL Query Execution time?

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm having issues on my server at the minute because some of the MySQL queries are taking a very long time to run, and hogging the resources on the server.

I'm already in the process of optimising all the queries to improve the performance, but as we use a fair amount of 3rd party applications on the server using mysql I was hoping to put in place a safeguard to prevent future issues.

What I need is something I can put in place server wide that will apply to all queries but with the possibility of overriding it on a per query basis for some of the more complex reports that do take some time to run.

I've spent time googling to find a solution but so far no luck,

Thanks for your help

Comment: set up daemon process, which is polling every X seconds `SHOW PROCESSLIST` from MySQL and kills all queries taking more than Y seconds

Comment: yeah I saw similar approach to this using PHP which gets all running processes and the execution times and then you can kill them with a mysql command. A clever idea, very surprising there is not something natively that protect against this. Seems strange that mysql will let processes essentially run forever and hog all the system resources in the process.

Comment: The base class DbCommand in .NET has a CommandTimeout property which sets the wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error.

Answer (score 3):

This is a purely php solution that seems to be the simplest solution from what I've managed to find so far.

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  $process_id = $row["Id"];
  if ($row["Time"] > 200 ) 
  {
    $sql="KILL {$process_id}";
    mysql_query($sql);
  }
}
```

And running this from a CRON script every 60 seconds.

If anyone does find a better solution to this issue please let me know

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following procedure to check for queries running longer than 300secs. the  event runs the procedure periodically and kills all long running queries.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE DBNAME.kill_long_running_queries ()
BEGIN

  DECLARE v_qid BIGINT;
  DECLARE v_finished INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE c_queries CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND = 'Query' AND TIME > 300;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

  OPEN c_queries;

  l_fetch_queries: LOOP
    FETCH c_queries INTO v_qid;
    IF v_qid > 0 THEN
      KILL QUERY v_qid;
    END IF;
    IF v_finished THEN
      LEAVE l_fetch_queries;
    END IF;
  END LOOP l_fetch_queries;
  CLOSE c_queries;

END

CREATE EVENT kill_long_running_queries
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 60 SECOND
DO CALL DBNAME.kill_long_running_queries();
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! Never heard of MySQL events before, needed to add `event_scheduler=1` line into _my.cnf_ to enable them.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-kill.html which is designed  specifically for that. From man page:

```
pt-kill - Kill MySQL queries that match certain criteria.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it using MySQL options.
But you can still do it using daemon process as @rabudde advised.

In this case, if you kill process you will abort transaction and it will be rollback.

Comment: Please be aware that rolling back transactions can also place a significant load on the server! Unfortunately this can hardly be predicted, but as a rule of thumb you should know that if a transaction has been running for a while and will touch many records, its rollback time will increase. This gets even worse when there are several transactions interacting (includes SELECTing) with the same rows.

Comment: Fortunately I can get the query being executed so will put something in place to allow non SELECT queries more breathing room. TBH so far had no issues with performance relating to INSERT/UPDATE/REPLACE all so far have been SELECT queries usually with mysql choosing the incorrect indexes, and surprisingly FORCE INDEX(primary) fixing about 90% of these queries!